# How to use CMAKE_CUSTOM_TARGET

Tags: cmake

actual I'm struggling with CMAKE_CUSTOM_COMMAND. Actually I try to define a separated make target for my demo sources while i got dependencies i could only solve after "regular" build, when any file is generated. This target should perform some steps after any regular build:

1. Compile sources
2. Create executables

Up to this point anything works fine using add_subdirectory command with separated CMakeLists files, but this fails when I try to solve dependencies which have not 
created yet (i.e. copy dll on windows platform to demo executable dir)

1. Copy dependencies (dlls ect.)

I've tried to use the CMAKE_CUSTOM_TARGET and CMAKE_CUSTOM_COMMAND commands. But I fail. How I could invoke a build of my demo sources using a separeted target?

Thanks for any help.
Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build one target after another you can use cmake [add_dependencies](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aadd_dependencies) command, specialy designed for this purpose.

```
set (MY_LIB_DEPS
 target1
 target2
 #...
 targetn)

add_library(MY_LIB source.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MY_LIB ${MY_LIB_DEPS} 3rd_party_lib)
add_dependencies(MY_LIB ${MY_LIB_DEPS})
```

Also copying dlls and executables typically is done during *installation*, not building (Using make - while running command `make install` just after `make`). To achieve this use [install](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3ainstall) command. For installing executable, for example, it can be used like this:

```
add_executable(my_exec my_exec_source.cpp)
target_link_libraries(my_exec ${MY_EXEC_DEPS})
#...
install(TARGETS my_exec RUNTIME
 DESTINATION ${MY_PROJECT_EXEC_INSTALL_PATH}
 RENAME "${MY_PROJECT_PREFIX}-main_exec")
```